In what sense does 多様性 imply "diversity"?
"Diversity" can often mean diversity in sexuality, gender, and race. But, strictly speaking, "diversity" in English can also imply diversity in viewpoints, age, experience, social-standing, wealth, etc..
In an anime (Yoru no Kurage wa Oyogenai), I encountered 多様性{たようせい}, which is given the definition "diversity". But there's two reasons that I'm not sure if it means "diversity" in the broader sense.

性 is part of the word, which implies gender/sex is an important factor.
In the context of the anime, a male bully is making fun of a girl for using a male Vtuber persona. He basically says "もしかして[君]って本当は男になりたいみたいな。多様性みたいな。最近{さいきん}流行{はや}ってるもな。"　This was basically translated as "Are you like, one of those people who actually wants to be a guy? That 'diversity' stuff? It's like a trend these days, huh?" by the official subs.

For those reasons, it leads me to think that 多様性{たようせい} may be more of a "loaded" term focusing on sex, gender, and race (similar to how the term is loaded these days in America). As opposed to the broader definition of the word that applies in any context, be it view-point, height, age, etc..
So yeah, essentially my question is, in what manner does 多様性{たようせい} imply diversity?

多様性 is just "diversity", and 性の多様性 and 性的多様性 are the phrases to express "sexual diversity". 多様な性 is "diverse sexes".

No offense but I can't help but recall an anecdote that when 相対性理論 was introduced to Japan, some people protested against this "immoral" theory thinking it is about 相対 "(archaic) a couple" + 性 "sex".

Working backwards:

多【た】 — "many"
様【よう】 — "kind, manner, style, type"

1 + 2 above yields adjective 多様【たよう】 — "of many kinds: varied, diverse"


性【せい】 — "character, essence, -ness"

(1 + 2) + 3 above yields noun 多様性【たようせい】 — "the character or essence of being of many kinds: diversity, varied-ness"



Note that 性【せい】 does not necessarily mean "gender"; there is no inherent "sex" meaning in this morpheme / word element.  Consider also 性格【せいかく】: "personality", or アルカリ性【せい】: "alkalinity, base-ness [in chemistry]", which demonstrate a marked lack of any "sex" sense.
